# Null pointer anomaly in Ararylist

Tags: java, arraylist

First, i initialized my `ArrayList` to `null`, then I tried to initialize it with a `String`, but it doesn't overwrite the `String`. Now I initialize my `ArrayList` with another `ArrayList` containing a `String` and it works, can someone explain it?
(implementation is done in java)

Comment: Can you show the problematic and successful code?

Comment: Please add the source code, so we can help you.

Comment: Can't imagine what you are saying. Please post a snippet.

Answer (score -1):

```
// This creates a new ArrayList paramaterized to store Strings
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

You can call various methods on list, now, such as add or remove, and you get do this at a specific index, just like you would with an array. The difference is the ArrayList can grow or shrink in size.

For some examples:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arraylist_class.htm